# SQL server - how to define query with table constructor

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I need to define query using table constructor with 5 records, where each record should contain only one digit (from 1 through 5)
There's syntax given for this question:

```
SELECT * VALUES(...)
```

My question is: how should I do this? Because I am not familiar with this type of a constructor .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select from **[`TVC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dd776382.aspx)** use this Syntax.

Use a `TVC` as the table expression in the statement’s `FROM` clause

```
SELECT *
FROM   (VALUES (1),
               (2),
               (3),
               (4),
               (5) ) AS num(Number);
```

**Result:**

```
Number
------
1
2
3
4
5
```